# JQuery unable to find controls on a page

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery date mask, but when I run the page it throws an error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method".

Now, the control that this particular JQuery is meant to be working is added dynamically to a repeater control. Through this, I have looked at the ids of the control, where it was breaking and stopping in Visual Studio and what is being shown on the aspx page. The ids are identical except of the "#" that JQuery has at the start, which is not on the page.

In my JQuery code I have:

JQuery(function ($) {

```
$('#<%=date.ClientID %>').mask("99/99/9999");
```

});

Is there away to tell JQuery not to include the "#" when finding the control? I have used UniqueID but this changes any underscore into "$", which is not the same as what is on the page. My only problem is with "#" sign at the start of the ID.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: The hash is used by jquery to let jquery know that it is looking for a html element with an id attribute. e.g.

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert($('#<%=date.ClientID %>').attr('id')); 
</script>
```

This code alerts the right id, so the '#' is not the problem. Check if mask() is a valid function and if your code runs before the textbox is on the page. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('#<%=date.ClientID %>').mask("99/99/9999");})
```

Note: the `<%=`ServerSideCode `%>` block MUST be on the aspx page, it does not work in a .js file!

Or you can add a classname as Ives suggested, then the server side code isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to include the mask library.

```
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To make things easier you can add a class (class="datemasked") for the control and then use the following to make it work:

```
$('.datemasked').mask("99/99/9999");

});
```

Comment: The mask library is on the same user control where the textbox is.

Comment: I am not clear by what you mean by adding a class to the control. Where is this added to the control?

Comment: You could add a CssClass to the textbox: <asp:TextBox ID="date" runat="server" CssClass="datemasked"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 0):

Try to split up your code and use Firebug to debug.
If you write:

```
var element = $('#<%=date.ClientID %>');
$(element).mask("99/99/9999");
```

And then step through the code, you can at least see if the element is found. You can also list all the available methods on the object to see that the mask function is available.

As Ives said, make sure that the library is included.

Edit:
From what I gather, your main problem is that you're mixing C# and JavaScript. The <% date.ClientID %> only makes sense in C#, so you need to somehow send this as a parameter to the function setting up the JavaScript.

A better solution, as described by Ives is to use the CssClass on the element and then use $('.classname') in the jQuery selector. This assumes that you only have one instance of the element though, which might not be your case.

Comment: I can't use Firebug due to the restrictive development environment I have to work in. The library is included on the user control. It is there. The Ids are different due to the "#"

Comment: As already explained, the # is not part of the name. It's simply the jQuery syntax for finding an element by it's id. The # is not interpreted as part of the name. Do a check on element and give an alert() if it's null or something.

Comment: Okay, i have add alert(document.getElementById("date")); and when the page is loaded it shows null, rather than object. So, it is missing the control. How do I fix this?